# error in integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Can someone explain me what I get wrong here ?

I have this integral
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{x(2 \ln x+1)} dx
\end{equation}

I set
$ u=\ln x $ and
$ du=\frac{1}{x} dx $
and so I obtain
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{1}{2u+1} du 
\end{equation}
and then the solution seems to be
\begin{equation}
\ln|2u+1|=\ln|2 \ln x+1|+c
\end{equation}
However, the correct solution is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\ln|2 \ln x+1|}{2} +c
\end{equation}

Comment: You forgot the chain rule.

Comment: Incidentally, the most general $c$ is a locally constant function on $\Bbb R\setminus\{e^{-1/2}\}$ that can have different values either side of $e^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
$$\int a\frac{f'(u)}{f(u)}du=a\ln\lvert f(u)\rvert +C$$
So in your case, we have
$$\int\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{2u+1}du=\frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert2u+1\rvert+C$$

By the way, without any substitutions you already had your integral in the above form, as
$$\int \frac{1}{x(2 \ln x+1)} dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2}{x(2 \ln x+1)} dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\left(\frac{2}{x}\right)}{2 \ln x+1}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln\lvert2\ln x+1\rvert+C$$

Answer (score 1):

That's because$$\int\frac1{2u+1}\,\mathrm du=\frac12\log|2u+1|.$$In general, if $F(x)$ is a primitive of $f(x)$, then $\frac1aF(ax)$ is a primitive of $f(ax)$ ($a\ne0$).